# Stored procedure encryption and master service master key, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

Is the Service Master Key (SMK) used to encrypt stored procedures in SQL Server 2008?

I know it is used for data, but what about database objects? If the Service Master Key is not used, then I would expect that if one were to do a database recovery from one server to another (without restoring the SMK) that the stored procedures would continue to work.

Is this true?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not used. Details about the encryption algorithm used to encrypt database objects you can find here: http://sqlity.net/en/1617/decrypting-encrypted-database-objects/

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the algorithm - and thus the attack method - remains exactly the same in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought this was true, but wanted to be sure.